# Taylor series about $x=0$ or Maclaurin series

Tags: calculus

> Find the Taylor series of $\frac{2+x}{1-x}$ at $x=0$.

I tried to find the Taylor expansion of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and then multiplied by $2+x$, so my final answer is $$T(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(2x^n + x^{n+1}).$$
Is that correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This is extremely hard to read. Please see this [tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference/) on typesetting.

Comment: It is:  $2 + 3 x + 3 x^2 + 3 x^3 + 3 x^4 + 3 x^5 +....$

Comment: So far so good. You are probably expected to collect terms with each power of $x$. If you write out the first few terms explicitly (without the $\Sigma$ you will see the pattern - as in @am301 's comment.

Answer (score 1):

We know that Maclauren series can be represented as $$M(x) = c_0 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{f^{(n)}(0)(x)^n}{n!}$$
where $c_0 = f(0)$.
So let's find the derivative of $f(x) = \frac{2+x}{1-x}$:
$$\dfrac{d}{dx}\frac{2+x}{1-x} = \frac{3}{(1-x)^2}$$
Then we find the second order derivative
$$\dfrac{d^2}{dx^2}\frac{2+x}{1-x} = \frac{3(2)}{(1-x)^3}$$
So for $n$-th derivative, we should get something like $$\dfrac{d^n}{dx^n}\frac{2+x}{1-x} = \frac{3(n!)}{(1-x)^{n+1}}$$

Substitute everything and we should get$$M(x) = 2 + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 3x^n$$

which is almost identical with what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
T(x)&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2x^n+x^{n+1} \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty2x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{n+1} \\
&=2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2x^n+\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^n \\
&=2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3x^n.
\end{align}

Hence, the Taylor series has the form $T(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$, where
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}2,&n=0 \\ 3, & \text{else} \end{cases}
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to express the Taylor series in the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, you can use the formula

$$a_n=2+\mathrm{sgn}(n)$$

where $\mathrm{sgn}(n)=0$ if $n=0$ and $1$ if $n\ge1$. But this is really just another way of expressing zugzug's answer, giving a name to a function that has a piecewise definition.